# Structure memory allocation and malloc() in c

Tags: c, malloc

when I defined a node in linked list I came across this confusion.
consider,

```
struct node *current = head;
```

here `head` is pointer to head node. and another way is,

```
struct node *current = (struct node*)malloc(Sizeof(struct node));
current = head;
```

both works the same so what is the difference between them?
How is memory allocated in first case?

Comment: No memory is allocated in the first case. Memory allocated in the second case is leaked. You should learn what is _pointer_, and what is done when you _assign it_.

Comment: then what happens in first case what is current?

Comment: Please make a [mcve], or at least show the declaration/definition/initialisation of "head".

Comment: @0___________ Great! you just killed someone's motivation to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the second version calls `malloc(sizeof(struct node))` and loses the returned pointer; i.e. it's a memory leak. You can get the same effect by doing:

```
malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *current = head;
```